# Find list of unencrypted nodes from Alfresco Content store

Tags: java, performance, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I have tried to query my DB to find nodes that are unencrypted that are not in alf_content_url_encryption. Due to the large volume of data (in the millions) it has returned an error. I am looking to create a Java Backend to do this but am unsure on the approach.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you did so far:  
* which query did you run
* which error did you receive
Since encryption is an enterprise feature: You should contact Alfresco Support to solve issues. That's what you pay all the money for.